# Microsoft Word Merge Field Problems

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I'm doing a mail merge to a template with data pulled from an Excel table. I'm attempting to add text if the letter is for Program A or Program B, and different text if it's from Program C. The method I'm using is this:

```
{IF {=OR({COMPARE {MERGEFIELD program}="Program A"},{COMPARE {MERGEFIELD
program}="Program B"})}=1 "True Thing" "False Thing"}
```

Pretty straight forward, but it's not working. In the course of my debugging, I encountered this problem:

```
{COMPARE {MERGEFIELD program}="Visual"}
(displays 1 when the field is "Visual")

{COMPARE {MERGEFIELD program}="Multidisciplinary"}
(always displays 0, even when field is "Multidisciplinary")
```

Can anyone provide some guidance on why this isn't working?

Comment: Just to ask the obvious question: does { MERGEFIELD program } on its own definitely result in the exact text "Multidisciplinary" (same upper/lower case, no funny characters such as a thin space in the text, etc. etc.) (If so I have no explanation - the test works as expected here).

Comment: I went so far as to copy the text exactly from the Excel sheet, but it made no difference. I did find a process that gave a solution, which I've posted so that this question can be closed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How do you put the { in? They all need to be inserted as the specific word functions. It seems your original line is missing many of them.

Check this answer for details on how the syntax needs to look: [How to compare many values with an OR statement in Word mergefields?](https://superuser.com/questions/792667/how-to-compare-many-values-with-an-or-statement-in-word-mergefields)

Comment: I use ctrl-F9 to put the braces in. And you're right, I'm missing some braces, and I'll edit to correct it. But do you have any explanation of why my second example isn't working?

Comment: The examples given under the link have blanks around the ` = ` signs. But I tried it myself, and I get 0 too (with and without the blanks). I think it might be because no specific data row is selected - maybe it works once you step through the data rows.

Comment: This issue presented itself as I stepped through the data. I appreciate the help, but that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

No real explanation of what the problem was, but I did find a solution: I changed my template to a normal Word document (Mailings Tab > Start Mail Merge > Normal Word Document) then re-attached my recipients list. Following these steps, the merge functioned as intended.

Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Comment: That's interesting - I don't remember a problem like that but which version of Word are you using? I will have another look...

Comment: I'm using Word 2016, but this type of error has presented itself in other version of word as well.