# Word if statements

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I use "OR" in if statements in Word?  I've tried searching with no luck.  I am just trying to compare two fields to check for values.  If either of the fields has a value I need to add text.

Comment: [duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/792667/how-to-compare-many-values-with-an-or-statement-in-word-mergefields)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare many values with an OR statement in Word mergefields?](https://superuser.com/questions/792667/how-to-compare-many-values-with-an-or-statement-in-word-mergefields)

Comment: I looked at that one and it's not what I need, thank yo

Comment: If the answers to the other question don’t help you, explain why. It would help if you would explain in more detail what you’re trying to do, and what you have tried.  For example, if you were concerned with only one input field, what code would you use? … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a variation using COMPARE which gives the result I think you're after - to find out if both fields are empty.  I've used QUOTE field to combine the results of both fields (so if both fields are empty, this QUOTE will be empty; if either or both contains a value then this QUOTE will have a value).  The COMPARE of the QUOTE will return 0 if QUOTE is empty, so the true result for the IF statement is do nothing because both fields are empty, otherwise at least one or both fields contain a value so insert your text.
[image]